# Is there a place where I can see the performance over different years of Motley Fool's Stock Advisor?

Tags: financial-advisor

I am considering subscribing to the Motley Fool Stock Advisor. All the reviews on them underline how rich one would be today had one followed their advice in 2002. That's impressive but not very helpful, today.

Is there a place where I can see the performance over different years? E.g. starting in 2010 and existing on 2015, the gain vs. SP500 would be this.

Comment: All stock pickers are completely, utterly, totally, useless.  As with every single stock picker, it's impossible that they carefully and honestly publish their stock picks - for the obvious reason.

Answer (score 2):

If it exists, the logical place to find that information would be their web site.  They offer a "30-Day membership fee back guarantee" so take the subscription, evaluate it and either continue after a month or get a refund.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I'd have to go through all their historic recommendations to buy and sell stocks and evaluate those stocks one by one? While doable, it's a big effort. Since it would benefit thousands of people, it's very suboptimal if each subscriber does it on one's own. Besides, as a complete dummy in this topic, I am likely to make mistakes while doing it and would very much prefer to pay for such evaluation. Therefore I am surprised that I cannot find it already done. Is there a flaw in my logic (and the original question, as I don't see it getting much attention)?

Comment: It's speculation as to what  you might have to go through.  They might provide a list of recommendations by price and date or perhaps they offer nothing. Sign up for the service and see what tools they offer.

Answer (score 2):

I like Bob's answer (and gave it an upvote). Another choice would be to look at the mutual funds Motley Fool has been running for a time now. They run their funds based on similar advice to what they are selling, and comparing them against the broader market for their lifetimes could give you some insight on the quality of said advice: https://www.mfamfunds.com/our-products/

Bust out your favorite tool and compare FOOLX to the S&P for any period you are interested in.